# I should get UTF-8 from JSON in Android app, but I get something else... may be ISO-8859-1, why?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, decode

I use volley-library for get JSON from server. On server JSON:

```
{
    "timeLabel": "10.30 вЂ“ 12.45",
    "location" : "РљРѕРЅС„РµСЂРµРЅС†-Р·Р°Р» 4",
    "short_info" : "РџР»РµРЅР°СЂРЅРѕРµ Р·Р°СЃРµРґР°РЅРёРµ вЂ“ РіР»Р°РІРЅРѕРµ РјРµСЂРѕРїСЂРёСЏС‚РёРµ",
    "info" : ""
}
```

And JSON, which I get in app:

```
{
    "timeLabel":"10.30 â 12.45",
    "location" : "ÐÐ¾Ð½ÑÐµÑÐµÐ½Ñ-Ð·Ð°Ð» 4",
    "short_info" : "ÐÐ»ÐµÐ½Ð°ÑÐ½Ð¾Ðµ Ð·Ð°ÑÐµÐ´Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ â Ð³Ð»Ð°Ð²Ð½Ð¾Ðµ Ð¼ÐµÑÐ¾Ð¿ÑÐ¸ÑÑÐ¸Ðµ",
    "info" : ""
}
```

And my code for request:

```
private void download() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://**",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    Log.d("stringRequest", s);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Log.d("news", volleyError.toString());
                }
            }) 
    {

    };
    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

What's wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: Your Java code has misplaced brackets, are you sure its compiling correctly?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Yes, I am. It's correct and normally compiling, and Its normally structure for request in volley. Where you see the error?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your server includes `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8`.

If `charset=UTF-8` is included in `Content-Type` header, search Volley's document for a way to specify a character encoding explicitly.